# Impulse response of a simple physical system

Tags: electric-circuits, dirac-delta-distributions

Consider a simple physical system consisting of a resistor with resistance $R$ and an inductor with inductance $L$ in series. We apply an input voltage $a(t)$ across the pair in series, and measure the output voltage $b(t)$ across the inductor alone. The formula tells us $$a(t)=RI+L\frac{dI}{dt}$$
Solve it, we know
$$I(t)=\frac{a(t)}{R}-\frac{a(t)}{R}e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}$$
Since $b(t)$ can be expressed as:
$$b(t)=L\frac{dI}{dt}$$
We have
$$b(t)=L\Bigg(\frac{a'(t)}{R}\Big(1-e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}\Big)+\frac{a(t)}{L}e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}\Bigg)$$
Now I am asked to solve $b(t)$ if $a(t)$ is defined to be the Dirac delta function, namely $a(t)=\delta(t)$. By substitution there is
$$b(t)=L\Bigg(\frac{\delta'(t)}{R}\Big(1-e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}\Big)+\frac{\delta(t)}{L}e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}\Bigg)$$
Here is the issue. The desired answer is $b(t)=\delta(t)-\frac{R}{L}e^{-\frac{Rt}{L}}H(t)$ where $H(t)$ is the Heaviside function. However, I have no idea what $\delta'(t)$ is and how the answer is obtained. Any help please?

Comment: Derivative of a Delta function is a doublet function

Comment: the 2nd equation for $I(t)$ is wrong, it does not satisfy your 1st equation.

Comment: *I have no idea what $\delta'(t)$ is.* See [Derivatives of the Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Derivatives_of_the_Dirac_delta_function)

Answer (score 0):

I’m not exactly sure what you are referring to by b(t), but for just solving the first equation in which you have a(t) as the Dirac delta function, one quite useful method for evaluating these equations is the Laplace transform.

Essentially you integrate your function times an exponential raised to -st from 0 to infinity, and for discontinuous functions like the Dirac delta, it gives you a nicer expression in terms of s. You of course would transform the other side, and since it is linear, this shouldn’t be too much trouble. After transforming both sides, you would just use basic algebra to solve for your transformed function, and then do the inverse transform to get back your original function.

In practice, one usually tends not to use the actual transform itself (and even less so the inverse transform), but instead opts for a Laplace transform table which will tell you everything you need. Just google ‘solving linear constant coefficient differential equations with Laplace transform’ along with a Laplace transform table and you should be fine.

Answer (score -3):

Your answer seems to correct if you applied delta function as input and looking for its response. Though differentiation of $\delta(t)$ is not possible but as delta function itself result of differentiation of discontinuity of step or Heaviside function, so we can do differentiation of delta function and that is, $\delta'(t)=0$.

Now putting this value of $\delta'(t)$ in your solution we have impulse response,

$b(t)=\delta(t)e^{-\frac{R}{L}t}\tag*{}$

where $\delta(t)$ is input value at time $t=0$.

The desired solution is for step function which is,

$b(t)=\delta(t)(1-e^{-\frac{R}{L}t})\tag*{}$

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to say both ”differentiation of $\delta(t)$ is not possible” and “we can do differentiation of delta function”.

Comment: The derivative of a delta function is *not* zero. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Derivatives_of_the_Dirac_delta_function).

Comment: @Ghoster Integration of delta function is constant, so its differentiation could be zero. Technically neither delta nor step is function but we are using them as function. There are no two equations for response, one is for delta function that is impulse response and other is for step function as it was desired answer for question asked.

Comment: *its differentiation could be zero.* No. The derivative of a delta function has a standard meaning and it isn’t zero.

Comment: @Ghoster So are you saying integration of delta function for any long range is not constant or 1. This also makes sense in question asked, impulse response is not growing function as first part of right side in answer assumed by questioner.